Strict partial order on $\mathbb{N}$ cancellation law
Let $k,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. I would like to prove that $k + m < k + n \iff m < n$ holds. Let us first consider ($\implies$). I tried to use proof by contradiction and by induction on $k$. The case $k=0$ is simple. Suppose it holds for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $(k+1) + m < (k+1) + n$. By the trichotomy property of $<$ we then have that either $m=n$ or $n<m$. The first gives a contradiction since we get $k+1<k+1$ which is always false. The case $n<m$ is not clear how this leads to a contradiction...
For the direction $\impliedby$ I have no clear idea how to start.

Cancellation law is usually defined as an axiom of the relation <, it is therefore a bit meaningless trying to "prove" it, without properly having defined <.
However if we define $m > n$ as $m-n \in \mathbb{N}$, the cancellation law follows from the fact that
$$ m - n = (m+k)-(n+k)$$

Forgot to state indeed that $m<n :\iff m \in n$
